# Custom includePath in VSCode MacOS with GNU GCC causes IntelliSense issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20

So I am following the getting started for the [Eigen library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html#title0). I am using Macos, with VSCode. I have also istalled [GNU GCC using Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gcc#default), so that I can use the full power of C++20, as Apple Clang seems to not fully implement everything.

For the following code

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m(0, 0) = 3;
    m(1, 0) = 2.5;
    m(0, 1) = -1;
    m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

With the following `c_cpp_properties.json`

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.4.0_1/include/eigen3"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13"
            // "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I get the errors `namespace "Eigen" has no member "MatrixXd"` and `namespace "std" has no member "cout"` from IntelliSense. To be clear, my issue is with IntelliSense, not with actually compiling the code.

However, when I set the compiler path to normal apple clang, it seems to be all fine. But then I can't use C++20. When compiling using `g++-13 main.cpp -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.4.0_1/include/eigen3`, it also works fine. Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: did you select you c_cpp configuration yet?

Comment: @starball the "Mac" configuration is selected yes. Same issue sadly :(